# How can access Uploaded File in Google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm new in python and I use `Google Colab` . I uploaded a `train_data.npy` into google Colab and then I want to use it . According to this link [How to import and read a shelve or Numpy file in Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212852/how-to-import-and-read-a-shelve-or-numpy-file-in-google-colaboratory)

when i run my code i face this error :

> TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Here is my code :

```
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))

with open('train_data.npy', 'w') as f:
f.write(uploaded[uploaded.keys()[0]])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an adjustment to your snippet that will save any uploaded file in the current directory using the uploaded file name.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

for name, data in uploaded.items():
  with open(name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
    print ('saved file', name)
```

Answer (score -1):

First upload your local data:

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()
```

Access it using:

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Filename.csv']))
```