# Trouble with Google Application Credentials

Tags: python, api, authentication, google-vision

Hi there first and foremost this is my first time using Googles services. I'm trying to develop an app with the Google AutoML Vision Api (Custom Model). I have already build a custom model and generated the API keys(I hope I did it correctly tho).

After many attempts of developing via Ionics & Android and failing to connect to the to the API.

I have now taken the prediction modelling given codes in Python (on Google Colab) and even with that I still get an error message saying that Could not automatically determine credentials. I'm not sure where I have gone wrong in this. Please help. Dying.

```
#installing & importing libraries 

!pip3 install google-cloud-automl

import sys  

from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1.proto import service_pb2


#import key.json file generated by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
from google.colab import files
credentials = files.upload()


#explicit function given by Google accounts 

[https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python][1]

def explicit():
from google.cloud import storage

# Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
# file.
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials)

# Make an authenticated API request
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)




#import image for prediction
from google.colab import files
YOUR_LOCAL_IMAGE_FILE = files.upload()


#prediction code from modelling
def get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id):
prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()

name = 'projects/{}/locations/uscentral1/models/{}'.format(project_id, 
        model_id)
payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': content }}
params = {}
request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)
return request  # waits till request is returned

#print function substitute with values 
 content = YOUR_LOCAL_IMAGE_FILE
 project_id = "REDACTED_PROJECT_ID"
 model_id = "REDACTED_MODEL_ID"

 print (get_prediction(content, project_id,  model_id))
```

Error Message when run the last line of code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
credentials = files.upload()
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials)
```

these two lines are the issue I think.
The first one actually loads the contents of the file, but the second one expects a path to a file, instead of the contents.

Lets tackle the first line first:
I see that just passing the `credentials` you get after calling `credentials = files.upload()` will not work as explained in [the docs for it](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb). Doing it like you're doing, the `credentials` don't actually contain the value of the file directly, but rather a dictionary for filenames & contents.

Assuming you're only uploading the 1 credentials file, you can get the contents of the file like this [(stolen from this SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309490/9267296):

```py
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
credentials_as_string = uploaded[uploaded.keys()[0]]
```

So now we actually have the contents of the uploaded file as a string, next step is to create an actual credentials object out of it.

[This answer on Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/4477#issuecomment-347765112) shows how to create a credentials object from a string converted to json.

```py
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials_as_dict = json.loads(credentials_as_string)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_as_dict)
```

Finally we can create the storage client object using this credentials object:

```py
storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

Please note I've not tested this though, so please give it a go and see if it actually works.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. I gave up trying to fix to issue, hence I switched to Nanonets and it works like a charm and in fact is is cheaper. https://nanonets.com/