# Read csv to sframe in google colab

Tags: python-2.7, export-to-csv, graphlab, google-colaboratory, sframe

I have created a new notebook of python 2 on google-colaboratory and installed sframe(!pip install sframe) but I'm unable to read the CSV file in sframe.
Any help?

Comment: Did you try anything? Do you have any specific error message? Please provide more details to your question - it will be easier to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a CSV file in a SFrame, you need to download either **turicreate** module or **GraphLab create** module.

Firstly, you need to import data into colab. So you need to recognize how are you accessing your file: local storage or google drive. You can use this link to achieve this: [Import data into Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory).

For downloading the turicreate module in google-colaboratory, do the following steps:

1) Install **turicreate** module using pip in colab.

```
        !pip install turicreate
```

2) Import the turicreate module.

```
        import turicreate
```

3) Use the **[turicreate.SFrame.read_csv](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/generated/turicreate.SFrame.read_csv.html#turicreate.SFrame.read_csv)** function to import the CSV file into the sframe. Assume that the content of the CSV file is stored as **'file.csv'** and the name of the SFrame is **'sf'**, use the code below to read the CSV data into a SFrame.

```
        sf = turicreate.SFrame.read_csv('file.csv')
```

That's it !!! You can also do the same with Graphlab create.

Refer to the API documentations over here:

https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/generated/turicreate.SFrame.read_csv.html#turicreate.SFrame.read_csv

https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.read_csv.html