# How to import Your own data to google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm kinda new in python and tensorflow. I want to run my Deep network on a collab for human activity recognition.
The problem is I don't know how to import my dataset to collab!
I already did upload dataset to Drive. (The dataset link is in below)
http://www.cis.fordham.edu/wisdm/dataset.php
and I want to just use the WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import data into Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory)

Answer (score 1):

You got to mount your google drive in your notebook

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

[Reference](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q)

Comment: I already did! Now how to import data?
sth like this?
dataset = read_data('/content/drive/My Drive/app/WISDM_ar_latest.tar.gz/WISDM_ar_v1.1/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt')

Comment: Yes. If it doesn't work please tell me what error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

> column_names = ['user-id','activity','timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis',
>   'z-axis'] data = pd.read_csv(('My
>   Drive/app/WISDM_ar_latest.tar.gz/WISDM_ar_v1.1/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt',header
>   = None, names = column_names)

```
  File "<ipython-input-26-033bf3a3f419>", line 2
    data = pd.read_csv(('My Drive/app/WISDM_ar_latest.tar.gz/WISDM_ar_v1.1/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt',header = None, names = column_names)
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302366/7376885) you have one redundant bracket that leads to syntax error. Try this

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = 'My Drive/app/WISDM_ar_latest.tar.gz/WISDM_ar_v1.1/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt',header = None, names = column_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey It's solved now!
All think you need to do is just upload or data to your drive.
(I uploaded in folder name: "app")
Then

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

Now by this code you can import the data (Edit: Moved drive.mount to next line):

```
data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/app/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt")
```