# What's the best way to use the Google Photos API with Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'd like to create photo albums with Google Photo and then use the album as an image source. I've searched around and found some examples of using python with Google Photos API, but this doesn't appear to be used much or at all.

Is there a best practice for getting photo albums into Google Colab? Is it possible that performance is an issue so other options would be better?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?hl=en&ref_topic=6128848), you can configure Google Photos to appear in your Drive file list.

Once you've done that, the files should appear in Colab's file browser once you mount Drive as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47019779/8841057

Comment: This does work to map the photos into google drive. However, they appear in a date time style folder system. The photos organized into albums aren't exposed via folders.

Comment: And Google stopped making photos available via Drive Starting July 10, 2019 [Google Photos and Google Drive will no longer automatically sync](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089?hl=en)

Comment: that link now describes how to move images from "drive" to "photos" only, not the other direction.