# Can skimage be used to read images from a local drive?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have a lot of jpeg images stored on my hard drive that I would like to read and convert to arrays using skimage.io.imread

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```py
import os
from skimage import io

os.chdir('C:/Users/HP User/Desktop/')

img = io.imread('filename.jpg')
```

When I run it I get the error message:

```
No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/HP User/Desktop/'
```

Comment: Are you sure the directory actually exists? Not only `os` supports your code normally, but I also ran your exact code in my machine and everything worked as expected

Comment: It definitely does exist.  I'm cutting and pasting the path from the "properties" menu of the image file (changing the backslashes to forward slashes).

Comment: The error message is definitely on the `chdir`, not on the `io.imread`.  For some reason, it's not finding the directory you're giving to chdir.  Try avoiding the issue, and simply putting the one line: `img = io.imread('C:/Users/HP User/Desktop/filename.jpg')`.  You _may_ get a different response.  (Or, you may get the exact same issue.)

Comment: Also try to check if your script isn't beeing permission denied by OS (although It's pretty unlikely since we are dealing with Desktop itself)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but still no luck.

Comment: So, I think it's an issue with using Google Colab.  I just tried everything using Jupyter Notebook, and it worked just fine.  In Colab, the default working directory is the mysterious '/content', and I can't change it.  I'd still like to use Colab, though.  Any ideas?

Comment: Colab notebooks run on a web server, not on your machine. So you need to upload your data to that server to access it. This question might be the one you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory

Comment: Thanks.  Mounting my Google drive or using ```files.upload()``` are workable, and I've been doing that.  I'd much rather avoid the upload widget or my Google drive and just do it the way I indicated above.  If this functionality is missing from Colab, it seems like a big omission.  For now, I'll use the workarounds.  Thanks for all the tips!