# When I run deep learning training code on Google Colab, do the resulting weights and biases get saved somewhere?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am training some deep learning code from [this repository](https://github.com/NVlabs/few-shot-vid2vid) on a Google Colab notebook. The training is ongoing and seems like it is going to take a day or two.

I am new to deep learning, but my question:

Once the Google Colab notebook has finished running the training script, does this mean that the resulting weights and biases will be hard written to a model somewhere (in the repository folder that I have on my Google Drive), and therefore I can then run the code on any test data I like at any point in the future? Or, once I close the Google Colab notebook, do I lose the weight and bias information and would have to run the training script again if I wanted to use the neural network?

I realise that this might depend on the details of the script (again, the repository [is here](https://github.com/NVlabs/few-shot-vid2vid)), but I thought that there might be a general way that these things work also.

Any help in understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use various weight saving techniques to save weights. I am not aware that colab is saving weights on its own, if you use keras you can use `model.save_weights(Path)`, there are other options for other framework. Otherwise start using random state. Thats is what I will advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**; Colab comes with no built-in checkpointing; any saving must be done by the user - so unless the repository code does so, it's up to you.

Note that the repo would need to figure out how to connect to a remote server (or connect to your local device) for data transfer; skimming through its [train.py](https://github.com/NVlabs/few-shot-vid2vid/blob/master/train.py), there's no such thing.

---

**How to save model?** See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory); for a minimal version - the most common, and a reliable option is to "mount" your Google Drive onto Colab, and point save/load paths to direct

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive') # this should trigger an authentication prompt
%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/'
# alternatively, %cd '/content/drive/My Drive/my_folder/'
```

Once cd'd into, for example, `DL Code` in your My Drive (see below), you can simply do `model.save("model0.h5")`, and this will create `model0.h5` in `DL Code`, containing entire model architecture & its optimizer. For just weights, use `model.save_weights()`.

[image]

Comment: The code is running with Pytorch - are the commands to save the model only valid with tensorflow?

Comment: @user1551817 Right, this is for TensorFlow/Keras - unsure about Pytorch, but that's a separate question; see, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch)

Comment: Use `torch.save(model)` for PyTorch