# Import file into python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm new to python and trying to learn a few exercises via colab. I want to import a CSV file that I saved to my desktop. Unfortunately, I keep getting a "cannot find file" error message. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpg = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Desktop\mpg2018.csv.csv")
```

I tried to change csv.csv to csv.txt or leave as just .csv but nothing works. Any help would be great!

Comment: Is your file really name `mpg2018.csv.csv` or is it `mpg2018.csv`?

Comment: Also you should try using forward slashes in your path. e.g `mpg = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/micha/OneDrive/Desktop/mpg2018.csv")`

Comment: I am not sure you can read files from OneDrive like that. OneDrive is being used as cloud storage in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import data into Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory)

Comment: _trying to learn a few exercises via colab_ Colab cannot directly access your local files like this. Take a look at https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb.

Answer (score 0):

Foward slashes will work in this function.

```
mpg = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/micha/OneDrive/Desktop/filename.csv")
```

Since you've imported "os", you could also use path.join()

```
p = os.path.join("C:\\", "Users", "micha", "OneDrive", "Desktop", "a.csv")
mpg = pd.read_csv(p)
```

Also, that file format repetition within the name seems unnecessary. It may lead to more confusion.

Comment: How do you know that is the issue? _Since you've imported "os", you could also use path.join()_ Or even better, they could use pathlib ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `colab.research.google.com`, which lives in its own cloud world and has no idea of what files are on your personal machine. However, if you

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
```

It will open a nice dialog box which will allow you to find the file in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

In  **files** section you find **Upload** button click on it   add your file in colab 
now simply import pd.read_csv(path)

how you find path: left click on csv file then select copy path and paste in place of path in pd.read_csv()