# Trouble in uploading a large file from google drive url to google colab

Tags: google-drive-api, upload, dataset, google-colaboratory

I need to upload a large file ( [Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J_t-TzR2rxp94SzfPoeuJniSFLfY3HM-/view?pli=1)) to google colab. This file is located on a google drive account.

Consider these situation:

1. My google drive is approximately full, so I could not upload it to my drive
2. My connection speed is low and downloading this file and uploading it to google drive is a great challenge for me.

Also, I read some stackoverflow pages like: [Import data into Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory) and these ones: 
[Download File from URL to Google Drive using Google Colab in Python](https://codingdiksha.com/google-colab-download-file-url-google-drive/) ,  [Get Started: 3 Ways to Load CSV files into Colab](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-load-csv-files-into-colab-7c14fcbdcb92) and [7 ways to load external data into Google Colab](https://towardsdatascience.com/7-ways-to-load-external-data-into-google-colab-7ba73e7d5fc7). But non of them was useful for my case. I also tried `!wget` command but it could not download a google drive link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a shared google drive link like this one:

[image: shared link]

Then share it with another person:

[image: share via email]

Now, go to your google drive and check **Shared with me**:

[image: Share file in google drive]

**Add shortcut to drive**: Now this file has been added to google drive and it is accessible in **colab**.

Finally, go to colab and run these commands:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


import os
os.chdir("drive/My Drive/Weights/")
```

And file is there!

[image: Uploaded file]